# Docusign Bulk Send Api Queue/Sent/Failed count is not accurate

Tags: docusignapi

Recently I am heavily dealing with Docusign Api. Especially Bulk Send Rest api method since we have requirements to send 30K envelope in 3-4 hours. Given the  [Api Rule Limits](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules), led us to leverage bulk send feature.

Since Bulk send has some limitation, like it has its own queue mechanism where queue size can not exceed 2000, I am implementing my solution by respecting to this limit.

To do that, I divided my bulk recipient file (30 K recipient) into 30 CSV file.

Then I initiate for each loop and inside the loop I am controlling queue size if the queued item count became 0 for the batch. During my many tests even though all email has been reached to my inbox, I have never seen queued property to become 0. If it would become 0, then I would send the next batch. But I could never do that

Below is the screenshot I took from ApiExplorer.

[image: Results of /v2/accounts/{accountId}/bulk_envelopes api call]

If I look deeper for Trial 3 to see what are those 24 queued items as seen below.

[image: Going deeper for trial 3]

I am getting following response.

[image: Issue]

As you can see from the latest screenshot, even though queued property indicates that there are some pending items, resultSetSize property shows 0 although I just queried queued items.

For this reason I am not able to build my logic based on sent, queued, failed property value. I thought, I could rely on them to successfully build my logic. If not, how can I overcome this problem ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance